# Calculate percentage from a array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

How can I calculate how many of the elements in a array like this have a non-empty data field, in percetanges?

```
[elements] => Array
        (   [abc] => Object
                (                    
                    [data] => Array ([0] => 'something')                      
                )    

            [def] => Object
                (                    
                    [data] => Array ()

                )

            ...
```

In this exemple it would be 50% because there are 2 elements, and 1 of them has something in data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$percent = count(array_filter($elements, function($ele){return !empty($ele->data);})) / count($elements) *100;`

Comment: @Jan  Turoň: Just provide one solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

That what loops are for:

```
if (sizeof($elements) != 0) { // Avoids division by zero
  $count = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($elements); $i++) {
    if (!empty($element[$i]->data)) {
      $count++;
    }
  }

  $pcent = ($count / sizeof($elements)) * 100; // You can use round($pcent) to avoid some horrible floats

  echo $pcent;
}
```